# Apple push notification with smaller payload length is not being receive by iOS 10 device

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, ios10, pushsharp

We have a app in which we need to send push notifications for different scenarios. But especially for one scenario the push notification is not being received by the iOS 10 devices. But the logs in the Backend (c# and SQL server) says the push notification was sent successfully and always says success. After a long debugging we found out that the payload for that notification is much less(<30 characters). When we increased that payload length(>60 characters) that device shows the notification.

Is there any change with the apple push notification in the iOS 10 regarding payload length? As i have gone through their documents only the maximum length is specified

`HTTP/2-based APNs provider API
Regular push notification: 4KB (4096 bytes)
Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notification: 5KB (5120 bytes)
Legacy APNs binary interface
Regular push notification: 2KB (2048 bytes)`

I am using push sharp dll to send push notification. Are there any change in push sharp for this?

Comment: There is no minimum size. Please include an example of the push payload your using. That could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved it by adding the apps name and a few default words before the actual payload to overcome this error and it works fine till now. But now in the latest iOS 11 and iOS 12 we don't have this problem.